# Animate height based on children's height

Tags: css, css-animations, animate.css

I have a container — imagine that it contains pages in an app. I’m using animate.css to slide from a page to another. Pages have different heights (according to their content), so the container has to resize to accommodate.

**I can’t for the life of me get the height to animate!**

The CodePen (and the following code) demonstrate a working sliding animation between pages but the container's height just changes instantly.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqbExY

HTML:

```
<button id=btn>animate</button>
<main>
  <section class="first">Little content</section>
  <section class="second">Lots of content ........</section>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  transition: height 1s linear;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}

.leave {
  position: absolute;
}
```

JavaScript (jQuery just for demonstration, in reality I'm using Angular):

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var $first = $('.first');

  $first.addClass('slideOutLeft animated leave').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',
    function(e) {
      $first.hide();
    });
  $('.second').addClass('slideInRight animated').show();
});
```

Comment: Give .first and .second a constant height, like this:  **.first{height:250px;.......}**

Comment: I can't, their heights are based on their contents. And even if I did, it still wouldn't work without attributing those heights to `main`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdmJOO

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to animate the height of the container, you should animate the height of the element within it. As a basic example, you could do something like:

[Codepen Update](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqbEJz)

CSS

```
.second {
  background-color: green;
  max-height: 0px; // Use max-height so you can animate without setting a fixed height
  transition: 2s;
  overflow: hidden; // Instead of display: none;
}
.height {
  max-height: 200px; // Height is dynamic up to 200px
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.second').show().addClass('slideInRight animated height');
```

Answer (score 0):

Transitions don't work with `height: auto`, but you can find approaches :

1- You can try to measure the height of each new div in javascript and set your `<main>` container to this height : the animation will trigger

2- You can use a little tweak and set the animation on `max-height` then modify the `max-height` to a bigger value than your div.